# Find specific keyword in API JSON response - Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to fetch a JSON response of multiple issues from an API and I am able to get the response successfully. My next part which I want to perform is to fetch/print only those lines which have specific keywords as "moviepass" and "login" in JSON tag "body". Here is my code

```
import json
import requests

api_url = '***************************************'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization':'Basic **************************'}

response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
#print(response.text)

words = ('moviepass', 'login')

def lookingfor(words):
    data = response.text
    for line in data:
        for word in words:
            match = re.findall(word, line['body'])
                if match:
                    print((word, line[]))


lookingfor(words)
```

My JSON looks like:

```
[{"tags":["moviepass"],"assignee_name":null,"app_id":"*******","hs_user_id":"*******","title":"1234","redacted":false,"updated_at":1611753805497,"messages":[{"body":"moviepass - Not '
 'sure if this is what you guys meant or not but here '
 'haha.","created_at":********,"author":{"name":"abc","id":"*****","emails":["abc@qwerty.com"]},"origin":"end-user","id":"*********"}]
```

Comment: `response.text` is a string i guess, so `for line in data:` iterate's over the letters.

Comment: @AbbasEbadian tried this way but getting error
data = response.text
for line in data:
    if any(word in line.get('body', []) for word in words):
        print(item)
Error - ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'```

Comment: Replace `data = response.text` with `data=response.json()` or `data = json.loads(response.text)`

Answer (score 0):

You dont need regular expression.You can use `json_data['tags']`
But if you want to use regular expression, you need to convert json to string by using

```
import json
json.dumps(json_obj) #returns same object but type of string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert JSON response and parse it - it's a list of [nested] dicts. You can use `Response.json()` method, no need to import `json`.

```
import requests

api_url = '***************************************'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization':'Basic **************************'}
words = ('moviepass', 'login')

response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
for item in data:
    if any(word in item.get('tags', []) for word in words):
        print(item)
```

Comment: Getting this error ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'```

Comment: did you do `data = response.json()` - this will convert your response to list of dicts.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. If you did data is `list` of `dicts`. Item will be a `dict`. Print `data` as well as `type(data)` and `item` and `type(item)`

Comment: Or take my code, replace `api_url` and credentials with real ones and run it.